# Is it thread safe to reassign a list in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I'm playing with two threads operating on an ArrayList. I know you can't modify the list while iterating, but Java is letting me reassign (replace) the entire list in a loop with no issue. Is this threadsafe?

```
public class Main {

    static List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hi", "there", "friend");

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {

        boolean isReassigned = false;

        for (String s: list) {
            System.out.println(s);
            if (!isReassigned) {
                new Thread(() -> reassignList()).start();
                isReassigned = true;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public static void reassignList() {
        System.out.println("Reassigning list....");
        list = Arrays.asList("goodbye", "old", "list");
    }
}
```

I expected concurrency issues after "hi", but I got "hi there friend".

I assume this works because Java does copy-by-value on references, but I'm worried my production app that reassigns the array every 1 minute might blow up someday. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Make it `volatile` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not seeing the updated list contents because the enhanced *for* loop uses an iterator behind the scenes. And hence, you are using the iterator (to the old list) to iterate over the data (even after the assignment is done). This means that both the lists are in-scope (and not Garbage collected). Once, `isReassigned` is true, if you get an iterator to the `list` you can see the new contents.

I've changed your code a bit (added an *else* block) to understand this

```
for (String s: list) {
    System.out.println(s);
    if (!isReassigned) {
        new Thread(() -> reassignList()).start();
        isReassigned = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Latest data " + list);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
```

This produces

```
hi
Reassigning list....
there
Latest data [goodbye, old, list]
friend
Latest data [goodbye, old, list]
```

A few other points:

1. You should not be setting `isReassigned` from the main thread. It has to be set after you assign the list.
2. As @Kartik points out in the comments, there can be visibility issues and the other threads may not see the made changes. Marking the list and the  `isReassigned` *volatile* will solve this.

Comment: (+1) changing to a regular for-loop outputs what the OP is expecting. However, it won't be reliable until the list is marked volatile or some synchronization is used, because the new reference of the list might not get "visible" to the other threads.